# How to get value from radio button bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I want get value from radio button that made by bootstrap with jquery

I try with this but not work

```
    $('#search-type input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=\'options\']:checked', '#search-type').val());
});
```

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="search-type">
            <label for="Search">Search for:&nbsp;</label>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="Photo" checked> Photo
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="Video"> Video
          </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify when you're trying to call your jquery code? Possibly you just need to place your event handler into [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function

Comment: When click submit button, but I try to rest it with alert

Comment: look at the Sumithran answer. I reproduced your html and jQuery code, but enclosed it into `ready()` handler in same maner and everythin is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){

            var radioValue = $("input[name='options']:checked").val();

            if(radioValue){

                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);

            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

Hope helpful.